# Exporting Drupal user account ID's through Civi search

Tags: drupal, groups, export, cms-integration, gdpr

I'm trying to export the Drupal User ID's for a particular Civi group, in preparation for GDPR and as a general clear out. I am able to search for all users in Civi which are a CMS user (and therefore have a Drupal account) but when I go to export and download this information none of the available fields will provide the Drupal User ID, the columns are just blank.

Is this my Civi getting confused and refusing to provide information (which it does do sometimes) or do I need to download this information in a different way.

Hope that makes sense and thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 4):

We needed to do something similar, though not GDPR related. Because the Export does not access the Drupal user fields, we created a simple View (page display) to give us this data, based on CiviCRM Contact.

We also used the [Views Export Data](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module and 'attached' the csv to the Page above. Note the page is not required, you can simply use the csv display via the URL you configure for it.